# Is there a faster way to assign a column to a dataframe (that has a condition) other than iloc (willing to use Dask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

df2.loc[(df2['feature'] == 0), 'package_loss'] =1

My code is above.  Here, I am trying changing a value to the column 'package_loss' to 1 if another column equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.where`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df2['package_loss'].where((df2['feature'] == 0), df2['package_loss'], 1).compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not as terse as @jezrael's answer, but allows more flexible transformations using `pandas` syntax:

```py
from dask.datasets import timeseries


def add_col(df):
    df = df.copy()
    mask = df["name"] == "Dan"
    df["new_column"] = 0
    df.loc[mask, "new_column"] = 1
    return df


df = timeseries()
df2=df.map_partitions(add_col)
df2.head()
```